# Blazor - How to focus on the first invalid field in EditForm

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a form in Blazor which utilized form validation, as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#example-form).

When the user tries to submit the form, and it fails validation, I'd like to focus the user on the first invalid `<input>` field.

How can this be done in Blazor WebAssemby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically set the `@ref` by using a `Dictionary` and adding onto Brian Parker's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72331934/22991031):

```
@foreach (var category in myModel.Categories)
{
    <input type="number" @ref="myComponents[category]" @bind=category.myValue />
}

@code {
    private Dictionary<ModelClass, ElementReference> myComponents = new Dictionary<ModelClass, ElementReference>();
  
    private async Task FocusFirstError(EditContext editContext)
    {
        foreach(var eref in myComponents)
        {
            if (editContext.GetValidationMessages(() => eref.Key.myValue).Any())
            {
                await eref.Value.FocusAsync();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `OnInvalidSubmit` and access the `EditContext`.

```
<EditForm @ref=editForm OnInvalidSubmit=@FocusFirstError ... 
...
    <InputText @bind-Value=@inputRegisteredUser.GivenName
               @ref=inputGivenName
               class="form-control"
               placeholder="Given Name"
               id="GivenName" />
...
```

```
private EditForm editForm;
// repeat for all inputs
private InputText inputGivenName;


private async Task FocusFirstError()
{
    var editContext = editForm.EditContext;
       
    // repeat for all inputs
    if(editContext.GetValidationMessages(() => inputRegisteredUser.GivenName).Any())
    {
        await inputGivenName.Element.Value.FocusAsync();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to cycle through all the inputs, so the code wouldn't need to be repeated?

Comment: @Draex_ I tried but could not see a way. My only other thought was to use JsInteropt to find the first via the `.invalid` css class.

Comment: // repeat for all inputs isn't scalable. Is there a way to automate that?

Comment: @Draex_ , you can use EditContext.Properties in a custom input, e.g. a MyInputText that inherits from InputText and gets the EditContext from the CascadingParameter and store itself in a component list in EditContext.Properties["MyComponentList"].